# puppeeter selecting bootstrap-select option not val

Tags: puppeteer, bootstrap-select

I will freely admit that with puppeteer I am struggling.  I'm using bootstrap-select jquery plugin to do drop downs.  Here is an example of one of Jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/9xr5af00/
I have tried numerous different ways of having jest - puppeteer click the dropdown and click an element on the dropdown.

(Not sure how to put puppeteer in a jsfiddle along with an example).
All the examples for puppeteer seem to indicate that I need to use the val html tag, however the bootstrap-select only uses the option tag.

This is one of the many things that I've tried

```
await page.click('#client-picker')
let value = "A"
await page.select('#client-picker',value)
```

However putting delays in it seems puppeteer doesn't actually scroll down the list.  WHich I guess is right since it's just trying to do a select on an element.  How can I make puppeteer scroll the list for an entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It create `div` element and you need to click the button with `data-id="client-picker"`, select the parent and select `li a` element that match with the value.

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  let value = "A"
  let clientPicker = document.querySelector('button[data-id="client-picker"]')
  clientPicker.click();
  let listOption = clientPicker.parentNode.querySelectorAll('li a')
  Array.from(listOption).find(item => item.textContent == value).click()
});
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much, this was the magic decoder ring that I needed.  I am able to select the text that I want then verify the results.  The only additional thing I had to do was to wait for the drop down list to get populated  with a await page.waitFor().  Although I know I can do it a more efficient way.